# Cannot get the result of joined table

Tags: sql, pdo

I want get all the fields of two tables, one called "team", and another "team_info" that buond the first with an FK. I retrieved the result using this query:

```
$sql = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM team
INNER JOIN team_info ON team.id = team_info.team_id
WHERE id = :team_id");

$sql->bindParam("team_id", $args["team_id"]);
$sql->execute();
$teams = $sql->fetchAll();
return $response->withJson($teams);
```

but this will return only the fields of the table `team`, how can I return also the fields of `team_info`?

Thanks.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`team`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`team` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `country_id` INT NULL,
  `link` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `update_at` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `FK_country_team_country_id_idx` (`country_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_country_team_country_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`country` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`team_info`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`team_info` (
  `team_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `country_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `venue_id` INT NULL,
  `shield_link` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `founded` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `phone` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `fax` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `official_site` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  INDEX `id_idx` (`team_id` ASC),
  INDEX `id_idx1` (`country_id` ASC),
  INDEX `venue_id_idx` (`venue_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_team_team_info_team_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`team_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`team` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_country_team_info_country_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`country` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_venue_team_info_venue_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`venue_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`venue` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Please supply table creation scripts as well as sample data. The query looks good to me, I would be curious to try it from my end with your data.

Comment: @MathieuTurcotte check update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM team <------
INNER JOIN team_info ON team.id = team_info.team_id
...
```

With this "*" you only refer to all columns inside of the "team" table. When you are using aliases that should not be a problem anymore.

for example:

```
SELECT t.*, ti.* FROM team t
INNER JOIN team_info ti ON t.id = ti.team_id
WHERE id = :team_id
```

Comment: i am glad i was able to help you :)

Comment: not arguing as it clearly helped OP, but can you explain why that is? I have been doing SQL for the last 15 years, and select * from ... always returned ALL columns from ALL tables for me... Care to explain the reason why it didn't work that time?

Comment: @MathieuTurcotte yes, sorry... i forgot to explain it, but added it afterwards

Comment: yeah but for me: SELECT * FROM team t
INNER JOIN team_info ti ON t.id = ti.team_id
WHERE id = :team_id

would have returned everything. Is it because you can use * under MySQL as long as each table has an alias? I NEVER, EVER join tables by their name... I ALWAYS use aliases. Could it be the reason?

Comment: what I mean is using only *, but with each table having an alias... I dunno, I'm confused by this. To me, OP's query should have worked, even though I would have used aliases myself

Comment: @MathieuTurcotte yes exactly, if you are using aliases that is the reason why you will get all the columns, but if you do something like "select * from table join something on somecondition" you are only refering to the "table" columns

Comment: @MathieuTurcotte yes it would also work to only use * when you are using aliases, but its just personal preference for me to do it like "a.*, b.*" so i have an better overview from where the data is coming.

Comment: I see! Thanks! I guess it was never a problem for me in 15 years because I use aliases 100% of the time. Not 99.9999%... 100%! lol. (unless it's a 1-table query, and even then, I usually add an alias anyway just out of habit!)

Comment: @MathieuTurcotte yes, i also made it to my habit to use aliases everywhere :) Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

you have to specified all the column after the select because u r using two table so u have to specify the column name

> instead of * u have to specify all the columns of both the table so u can get the result from both tables